# Configure SSL (HTTPS) for my Django (Elastic Beanstalk) Backend API

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

I've been struggling the past week learning AWS to deploy my React - Django application to AWS. My react stack is successfully deployed to AWS Amplify, took no time at all. After deploying my Django stack to Elastic Beanstalk, I've stumbled on the following error:

```
xhr.js:178 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://amplify.url' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.elasticbeanstalk.com/'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

My question is, how do I configure https to my django eb application?

I purchased a domain for my front-end, but do I also have to purchase a domain for my back-end api, or do I use a subdomain? I'm having trouble finding instructions for the best practices, and how to implement them. If anyone can give me advice for configuring my elastic beanstalk load balancer, that would be great, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck like you were, and I saw your answerless question. I told myself I'd write something if I made progress on it.

Here's basically what I created that ended up working:

1. Django REST API app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk, React front-end on S3
2. Domain resource records managed by Route53
3. Amazon Certificate Manager SSL certificate for my domain (I used a wildcard *.mydomain.com)
4. Configure the Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer to listen on port 443 and associate it with the SSL certificate you created on ACM. (Follow [this excellent article by Rick Christianson](https://rickchristianson.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/getting-a-django-app-to-use-https-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/).)
5. I ended up installing [django-health-check](https://pypi.org/project/django-health-check/) for Elastic Beanstalk to measure my app's health, and to use it as the health check endpoint that Rick references in his article.

I'm still learning more about how to do this properly. For example, once you do this, you'll need to start managing static files differently. I'm looking at [articles such as this one](https://betterprogramming.pub/production-django-elastic-beanstalk-part2-4501caf7d8fb#fa4f) to try and piece it together. Good luck—hope this helps you or someone else in our shoes.